# Restricting commands to procedure only in MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, security, permissions, mariadb, fivem

I've put together a FiveM server using alot of public code and discovered there are cheat systems out there that allow the user to corrupt or delete the underlying database. The reason is because they can inject Lua scripts which can contain DROP, DELETE INSERT and UPDATE and if they know the schema potentially could do whatever they like.

My intention is to deny access to every command except for SELECT and move all the other logic to stored procedures. The thing is that the user executing the proc will be the game user account which if locked out would also be blocked server side? Am I able to deny access from calling applications but allow access from within a stored procedure or have the procs execute as a different account vs the normal SELECT statements? Are there any other considerations or designs that could work? I'll be using parameters across all calls to help guard against injection, but I'm fairly new to MySQL so wondering what other steps people take for these scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can give the MySQL user privilege to call procedures only. Then the procedures execute with the privileges of the user who defined the procedure.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html the parts about `SQL SECURITY` which has choices `DEFINER` or `INVOKER`. The default is `DEFINER`, which is what you want.

However, you would also need to deny SELECT privilege to the app user. A malicious user can cause problems with nothing but SELECT privilege. They can't change data, but they can overload the database server.

So you'd need to implement *every* database query, both reads and writes, in a collection of stored procedures.

Here's an alternative suggestion: Allow the app to work as it does today, where the app connects using its username and does SQL queries directly.

But if the user wants to invoke their Lua script, only allow that on a separate database connection, using a different MySQL user with limited privileges. Basically only the `EXECUTE` privilege on a specific schema. You can implement a set of stored procedures that the Lua script is allowed to run, and put them in that schema. Then Lua scripts cannot do other tasks that the app does, a Lua script can only run the finite set of procedures you want to allow them to run.

Comment: Thanks for that. The user lua scripts that could potentially take us down are maliciously injected ones and the entire Role Play framework runs mysql commands from lua. I'm thinking that I need a way to know which calls could be "known and trusted" ones. I'm thinking I could make a FiveM proxy resource where I could move all the commands from the solution to. The default mysql-async resource could be left to invoke anything on a connection with restricted access, but the trusted commands in the new resource would run on another connection.

Comment: Well, this is probably an education opportunity. Do you think it's a good software design to allow clients to upload code functions and then just run them verbatim on your server?

Comment: No. I did clearly say "maliciously injected". We are not letting people run their own stuff by design. I even said in my initial question "there are cheat systems out there that allow the user to corrupt or delete the underlying database", again not our intent but something we're trying to guard against.

Comment: We have an anti cheat system on our server which guards against attacks, but it's not 100% perfect. We aren't deliberately allowing this but we discovered last night with someone who was using a strong cheat system that they have the ability to inject their own resources and run any SQL statement they like. Rather than rely on anti cheat purely, I wanted to investigate if we could harden our internal code against attacks by architecting some protection techniques to cater for edges cases where they may slip through.

Comment: We don't write the game client incidentally, only the backend server customisation. We are at the mercy of vulnerabilities in the game client.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, one way or the other you have some development work to do. You could either reimplement all SQL code as stored procedures, and rely on the privileges as described above. Or spend the time trying to plug the security vulnerabilities. Read my general [arguments against using stored procedures](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-reasons-not-to-use-or-not-use-stored-procedures/answer/Bill-Karwin) before you start.

Comment: The stored proc approach wasn't my preferred option which is part of why I wanted to seek advice. I work for large departments which lean towards them heavily but they're not a create way to go in my mind. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Actually, I think this can be done even cleaner with better async management writing the proxy DAL resource in C#.